# What's the easiest way to group numbers in an array into groups of 3 or 4 in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have 1 - 50 in an array, I want to group 1-3 in group 1, 4-6 in group 2, 7-9 in group 3 and so on, kind of like displaying quarters in a year.  What would be the easiest way to do this?  Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array three at a time. Use `-subarrayWithRange:` to create each group, and do what you like with the groups.